# Unable to cut out half circle from div with clip-path

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use clip-path to cut out a curved shape from my div(blue part) but clip-path circle doesn't have that option I guess. I want to use clip-path as that will be responsive by default; instead of `:after` cause it messes up everything in small screens. This is a photo of what I want to achieve:

[image: demo]

This is the code:

```css
.bg-overlay {
    width: 76%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: darkblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    clip-path: circle(90% at 50px 23px);
}

.wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);  
  margin: 20px;
  background: cyan;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-overlay"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a radial gradient to achieve this effect by creating a transparent circle "inside" the background color you want:

```css
.bg-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 90%, transparent 49.9%, darkblue 50%);
}

.wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
  background: cyan;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-overlay"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think applying the `clip-path` to the other `div` does the trick. Or I might be misunderstanding your question.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.bg-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;  
  background: cyan;
  z-index: 0;
  clip-path: circle(90% at 115% 70%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-overlay"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```